# Problem with configuring a subdomain through Route 53 to forward to an external web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53, amazon-certificate-manager

I recently transferred a domain from shoppify over to AWS. The transfer went well (took 5 days). but now that I want to start using it I can't seem to do anything with it. I suspect that there is an error in the configuration somewhere and would love it if someone could help me figure it out

## What am I attempting?

I'm trying to forward traffic from my own sub domain ( https://docs.gisli.games ) over to my personal wiki page ( https://publish.obsidian.md/gisli-games-public )

Here is what I've tried

## Creating a CNAME record for the sub domain

**Step 1:**

I created a hosted zone with my domain name ( gisli.games )

- Type: Public Hosted Zone (The default selection).

This creates 2x records

- NS record that points to 4x aws dns servers
- SOA record that points do aws dns server

I can now go and press "Test Record" at the top of the page and it gives me the message "No Error"

**Step 2:**

- I create a new record with the name (docs)
- I pick the record type CNAME (*which is supposed to Route traffic to another domain...*)
- I set the value to the URL I want : "https://publish.obsidian.md/gisli-games-public" (But I skip the HTTPS part in the beginning so its only "publish.obsidian.md/gisli-games-public"
- TTL(300) (default value)
- Routing Policy=Simple Routing (default value)

**Result:**
When i go to the URL in a browser I get "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

## Trying to add Certificate through ACM

I think I read somewhere that I might need an HTTPS certificate for the domain, so I tried that too.

**Step 1**
I open up the certification manager in aws (ACM) and request a new certificate

My only option is to "Request a public certificate

Fully qualified domain name I type in *.gisli.games (which if I understand correctly creates a certificate for all the subdomains)

- DNS validation (Default)
- RSA 2048 (Default)

**Step 2**
I now select the certificate from the list and press "Create Records in Route 53" which I believe adds a record in order to validate the certificate.

When I press create record I get a new CNAME record that looks something like this _3927XXXXXXX.gisli.games which points to _f8281XXXXXXX.hcnplcfwms.acm-validations.aws

## The problem

- https://docs.gisli.games/ always returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
- The Certification Manager never gets passed **Pending validation** (I've waited 2 days)

I also tested to forward docs.gisli.games to a public simple html file (from S3) that is publically accessible but it still doesn't work

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with an SSL certificate in ACM? Those can only be used with AWS Load Balancers, API Gateways, or CloudFront distributions. Are you using any of those 3 services?